# res.download in node.js not renaming file in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

[As per the express 4.x documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download), we should be able to rename a file before it is presented to the user in the browser in the following way: **res.download(path, desiredName)**

In my code, I have this, to try to see what happened:

```
res.download(fpath, "hello.jpg");
```

And when I try to download the file in **Chrome**, I get the "hashed" name of the file, as I store it in the filesystem to avoid same name collisions, look at the images:

[image]

But in microsoft edge (non chromium variant), I get the intended name of the file:

[image]

What should I do to force chrome to accept the intended filename instead of keeping the name in the file path?

```js
router.get("/downloadfile/", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let fileId = req.query.id;
    let fileInfo = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/files/getfile/${fileId}/`
    );
    let fpath =
      __dirname +
      "/../public/ficheiros/" +
      fileInfo.data.userAt +
      "/" +
      fileInfo.data.name;
    res.download(fpath, "hello.jpg");
  } catch (error) {
    res.jsonp(error.response.data);
  }
});
```

**EDIT: Here's how I call the download, on the front end side:**

```js
  if (f.mimetype == "image/png" || f.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
    var ficheiro = $('<img src="' + f.path + '" width="80%"/>');
  } else var ficheiro = $("<p>" + f.originalname + "</p>");
  var download = $(
    '<div><a href="/posts/downloadfile/?path=' +
      f.path +
      "&id=" +
      f._id +
      '">Download</a></div>'
  );
```

Comment: can you show how you call `/downloadfile/` from the html/js side?

Comment: also what does the `content-disposition` response header show from the request in Chrome?

Comment: @AndrewLohr how do I check content-disposition? As for the other question, check edit

Comment: if you open the chrome developer console and go to the network tab you can check out things about your requests.

Comment: also try adding `download="hello.jpg"` as an attribute to your anchor tag. I am unsure why Chrome wouldn't honor the header, but this might solve your issue at least. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download

Comment: Interesting, some files are properly renamed upon download, and they are all jpeg files of roughly the same size and dimensions. The download attribute did help resolve the problem, but I'm still interested in knowing what is happening. I did confirm and all files have the "originalname" attribute in the database so there's no case of me accidentally sending an undefined value.